# RevoScaleR Hadoop commands issue

Tags: r, linux, azure, hadoop, microsoft-r

I've created a virtual machine on Azure. Now I'm able to remoteLogin to the VM but unable to copy files to Hadoop.

```
remoteLogin(deployr_endpoint = "http://dns-goeshere", session = TRUE, diff = TRUE, commandline = TRUE, username = "admin", password = "Yourpassword")
library(RevoScaleR)
```

Until here I'm fine. I copied required file to the VM using `pscp` and I checked the file is present in `root` folder. I also gave all permissions to the file.

Now when I try to copy the file to hadoop and received following message:
[image]

Comment: Does the user "instructor" have access to /root/Flightdelaydata.xdf?

Comment: Yes, I gave permission to instructor and restarted server but still same error.

Comment: Is the VM you're remote logging into also the edge node?